# Unwanted control characters

Tags: php, email

The user input in my website an email address sometimes appears like this and is saved in the database `accounts@somesite.co.ukÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â` or similar.
In the resulting printout it is like this `accounts@somesite.co.uk             �`
I think these are space characters from a non-UTF-8 charset.
I have tried using a regex which I am sure is wrong

```
$email = preg_replace('/[\t ]/', '', $email);
```

and I have tried

```
$email=trim($email);
```

Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: Are you forcing encoding to UTF-8 before saving the data to the db? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Start by finding out what those byte values actually are - use `urlencode` to make a debug output of the value, and then check for the %xy percent encoded characters. If it is just some sort of whitespace, then try and simply `trim` the value.

Comment: I believe this is the regex you were trying to do: `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email);` (remove all whitespace characters) - yours would have simply removed all tab characters.

Comment: Thanks all, I am learning something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)` to remove all invalid chars or `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` if you prefer to check the email and warning the user if there is some problem

Comment: Thanks for that, I have run out of time to try any of these options. I will come back later to report results.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant. The filter did it. I tried the regex but it had no effect. BTW the UTF-8 statement is in the HTML head. I guess that forces it but not sure. I didn't try the urlencode but it is something to remember with future problems.

Comment: The filter solution works well but it has given me a new problem. All of the spaces are removed from the text that is filtered. Is there a way to change the control character into a space? The character is ascii 194 and it needs to change to 32. I expect a regex would do it but I cannot get my head around them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I am using the filter on a text input that also suffered from the control character. $text= filter_var($text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);